# ER: Emergency Room

Tags: discussion

The subsite's logo is ER, which I know as Emergency Room, is that joke on purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[All of the beta sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) have the same basic logo with a two-letter abbreviation added to resolve ambiguity.

[image]

When the site graduates from beta, the design will include a logo made specifically for the site.

Comment: I read this as, "Yes, we were making a joke," laughed, and then I moved on.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen E&R used as an abbreviation in several places by several people.   I think it

1. Is easier to pronounce (You don't try to read it "uhr"),
2. Is more iconic, and
3. Distinguishes us from the medical term.

I'm not trying to say that the image needs an ampersand to avoid issues of mistaken identity.  I hope that any legitimate emergency room logo wouldn't be so sketchy...

Comment: Yeah, I have started typing E&R and it seems to be more clear.